# Operator functions with pointers to objects

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

A newbie question. Lets say we have two objects from a random class, saved in pointer like this :

```
   RandomClass *obj1 = new RandomClass;
   RandomClass *obj2 = new RandomClass;
```

Now when you call a function from these objects you can simply do it like this:

```
   obj1->randomFunction();
```

But how do you use operator functions from that class, for example a overloaded multiplication operator ( with normal objects):

```
   obj1 * obj2
```

And if its not possible how would you go about it to solve this problem ( writting a new function is not possible). Sorry if it may be a stupid question but i'm abit confused on how this works with pointer arithmetic and so on.

Comment: @ Fredrik Boston Westman use dereferenceing operator (*)

Answer (score 2):

You can dereference the pointer like this:

```
RandomClass *obj3 = new RandomClass();
*obj3 = (*obj1) * (*obj2);
```

If you no longer need the two objects that you multiplied together don't forget to clear memory appropriately as well as the code above will allocate new memory on the heap for `obj3`.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your variables are pointers, you need a `*` when you declare them.  I think you meant to have two different variables, too:

   ```
   RandomClass *obj1 = new RandomClass;
   RandomClass *obj2 = new RandomClass;
   ```
2. Dereference the pointers:

   ```
   result = *obj1 * *obj2;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The first bit of code isn't valid C++ (looks more like Java).  This is valid C++:

```
RandomClass* obj1 = new RandomClass;
RandomClass* obj2 = new RandomClass;
```

To multiply the objects pointed to by `obj1` and `obj2`, dereference them (`*obj1` and `*obj2`).  The code might look like this:

```
(*obj1) * (*obj2)
```

`obj1` is a pointer; `*obj1` is the thing it points to.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean

```
RandomClass *obj1 = new RandomClass();
RandomClass *obj2 = new RandomClass();
```

If you want to multiply the two, you need to deference the pointer to get at the actual value.

```
multRes = (*obj1) * (*obj2);
```